# Java- Execute Shell Command Not Working

Tags: java, shell, execution

I'm making a simple Java socket program that sends text from one computer to another.

Code:

```
    Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Starting Server...");
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(7777);
```

---

The program binds the socket to port 7777 on line 3 on the code example above.
However, this program sometimes returns a BindException. To fix that, I added this line of code before the bind occurs:

---

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -t -i:7777 | xargs kill");
```

So, in all:

---

```
    Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Starting Server...");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -t -i:7777 | xargs kill");
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(7777);
```

---

This ***should*** run the shell command to kill any processes running on port 7777.
But, it doesn't. If type the same command into Terminal.app, It works, and if I use the same syntax as line 4 of the above example and use a different command, like "say hello", that command works, but not the kill one.

---

So,

## Why does that command not execute?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything I can change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) will *not* launch the command through a shell, whereas this is required as you use a *pipe*. Try that instead:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
              new String[]{"sh","-c","lsof -t -i:7777 | xargs kill"},
              null, null);
```

I you need to *wait for completion* before continuing execution, use [`Process.waitFor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
              new String[]{"sh","-c","lsof -t -i:7777 | xargs kill"},
              null, null);
int exitCode = p.waitFor()
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great!!  I also needed to add a `Thread.sleep(156)` below the command execution to give it time to execute. I found, on my computer, that `156ms` was the minimum amount of time I could use.

Comment: @user3731821 I've edited my answer to point out `Process.waitFor`. Definitively more robust than empirical timing ;)

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't wait long enough on my computer. I bind the socket directly after I kill the processes on the port, Should I be doing something else first?